# React-native, difference between constructor and componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm developing a couple classes in react native, and this comes up:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      days: [{text: 'Sofort', id: 1, selected: true}, {text: 'Morgen', id: 2, selected: false}, {text: 'Montag', id: 3, selected: false}, {text: 'Samstag', id: 4, selected: false}, {text: 'Sonntag', id: 5, selected: false}]
    }
  }

  onDaySelection(selectedDay) {
    // some logic to change the selected day
  }

  render() {
    <Bar data={this.state.days} callback={this.onDaySelection(selectedDay)}>
  }
}
```

Bar class:

```
class Bar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource(
      {rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id}
    )

    this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.days),
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource(
      {rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id}
    )

    this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(newProps.days),
    }
  }

  renderRow(rowData) {
    let tick = rowData.selected? (
      <Image source={require('../assets/images/Checkbox.png')}/>
    ): (
      <Image source={require('../assets/images/CheckboxEmpty.png')}/>
    )
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={ () => {this.props.callback(rowData)}}
          style={appStyles.flowRight}
        >
          {tick}
          <Text>{rowData.text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see I had to implement the method componentWillReceiveProps on the Bar class, why is this? why is the constructor not called again, is it because store is not being updated? is this a correct pattern to do this?

EDIT: it seems my question was not clear, in the sense that there are other components that receive props, only have a constructor and update accordingly whenever their props are updated, ex:

```
class CustomCarouselIndicator extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    let indicatorArray = []
    for(let i = 0; i < this.props.length; i++) {
      indicatorArray.push(i)
    }

    let indicators = indicatorArray.map(index => {
      let isSelected = index == this.props.selected
      //Some more logic
    })

    return (
      <View style={[appStyles.flowRight, {flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems:'center'}, this.props.style]}>
        {indicators}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Whenever I change the selected prop, the component gets updated no need to implement componentWillReceiveProps.

Both of this classes are used in my codebase, yet on one I have to implement the will receive props method and on the other I did not have to do anything to get the component to update when new props where passed to it.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A constructor is only called once. componentWillReceiveProps is called whenever the props are updated; that is the correct place for this sort of logic.